# Cypress: How to scroll AG-Grid Table

Tags: cypress, ag-grid-angular

I would like to scroll to a specific column in the AG-Grid table [Ag-Grid table](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-sizing/).
The cypress command scrollTo() doesn't work for me for this kind of tables.
Do you have a idea how i can solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide more details ? is it slider? or you want to move specific position ?

Comment: Appreciate the link for some examples of the table. Is the AG-Grid table in your app in an iframe?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found a solution for my scroll problem.
Now I use the AG-Grid API [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/).

Example:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('ensureColumnVisible', (component: string, colId: string): Cypress.Chainable<void> =>{
    return cy.getGridApi(component).then(api => {
        api.ensureColumnVisible(colId);
        return cy.log(`Scrolling column: '${colId}' was successfully!`);
    })
});
```

cy.ensureColumnVisible('nameOfgrid', 'colID');

Comment: Where does cy.getGridApi() come from?

Comment: Will definitely upvote if you can point me to how you define or get getGridApi

Answer (score 1):

did a work around for this by using keyboard command using .type

Comment: Could you provide example? Did you use downArrow in type()?

Comment: yes.from the table i choose a cell to start with closest to the target cell.then click that then added.type('{downArrown}') dependes on how many you need to go to the target cell. This is my workaround as i wasnt able to make it work the cypress aggrid plugin